# Can e2fsck be suspended?

Tags: suspend, fsck

I have a large hard disk partition. I would like to launch e2fsck on it so that i shall suspend its progress, be able to reboot and resume e2fsck from where it was suspended.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, that is not possible.

Woudn't make sense, since data is going to be changed in the FS while rebooting on most systems (e.g. system logs)

Comment: Nothing will change an unmounted FS at shutdown, and nothing will change it at startup either if it isn't mounted automatically.

Comment: Yeah, i do not want to mount it during e2fsck, so it is not changing.

Comment: The fsck type programs are written so that they are careful not to leave stuff in an inconsistent state if they should crash or killed, but that is a rather weak guarantee...